# Use caches_action with multi cache_store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, redis

How to use caches_store with multiple config.cache_store? For example, I have config file for caching:

config.cache_store = :redis_store

In controller, for example, ProductsController I want to use caches_action for action show, but I want to save data in another redis server, not the one specified in the config file. How to do that?

Comment: https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects/issues/181

Comment: @ImreRaudsepp This is an abstract example. I need a concrete example.